# AdMob native AD lag

Tags: android, performance, admob

I have a `NativeContentAdView` in a `ListView` item. When I call `setNativeAd(NativeAd)` on it, a noticeable lag happens. All AdMob class and method names are mangled (`zzdt`, `zzalp`, `zzow` etc) so I omit them.

Things AdMob performs in `View#onAttachedToWindow` callback:

- registers several `BroadcastReceiver`s (each requires a Binder transaction) (sum ~10 ms)

Things AdMob performs in `OnScrollChangedListener#onScrollChanged`:

- dozens of DP-to-PX conversions, calling `Display#getMetrics` and triggering a Binder transaction for each conversion (sum ~7 ms)
- generates some JSON (~8 ms)
- evaluates some JS (~7 ms)
- creates a `WebView` instance (~5.5 ms), sets it up (~9 ms), asks it to `loadUrl` (~7.5 ms)

Inside `Handler#handleCallback`s (i. e. `Handler#post`):

- Creates a `WebView`, sets it up, adds to Window and evaluates JS (~27 ms)
- Gets packageInfo (IPC), creates a `WebView`, sets it up, asks to `loadUrl`, checks permissions (IPC), parses JSON, gets packageInfo one more time, introspects resources via `Resources#getIdentifier`, gets activityInfo (IPC) (sum ~40 ms)

Obviously, all these heavyweight operations are leading to jerky scroll.

What should I do to avoid lags or what I'm possibly doing wrong? Why don't AdMob native AD is as slow in other applications I've seen?

Using AdMob/GMS v. 10 and/or 11, but 16 shows the same lags.
All measurements are taken with [Nanoscope](https://github.com/uber/nanoscope) on their special emulator, but lag on a real not-so-old Nexus 5 is even worse.

Comment: Same is happening with me. Have you found anything on it ?

Comment: Yep, I've quit this job.

Comment: AdMob native ads are laggy AF still. Binder calls all over the place, etc. Terrible performance in RecyclerView.